# converting a DB2 query into oracle query

Tags: sql, db2, oracle11g

Previously we used DB2 as database, but now we are migrating to Oracle. Now, in our project we have extensively used sql's that were Db2 specific.

Is there any way to convert those DB2 specific queries to oracle supported queries.

Thanks

Comment: the question is pretty vague... any query posing a problem ? post some query with desription of the "wanted result"... without that noone can construct an oracle query to help

Comment: I hope you've investigated some other databases. Oracle is about the least standards-compliant, most idiosyncratic choice... your migration path from DB2 to other databases would probably be easier.

Comment: @Daniel, the migration path might be easier, but there are many other reasons to switch a database. Oracle has some of the richest feature sets out there and is very fast for large databases... In that way, it's not necessarily "idiosyncratic". What database would you choose and why?

Comment: I would try to choose the right one for the job. It's not unlikely Oracle is it. I just wonder because DB2 is extremely capable. I just migrated several in-house apps from Oracle to PostgreSQL. We weren't using a fraction of its capabilities, but paying a lot for it. All I mean about Oracle being idiosyncratic is that its syntax usually deviates from the SQL standard more than most other databases. (They all do; it's a matter of degree).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a lot of work ahead!

Between DB2 and Oracle, some important differences are (just an arbitrary enumeration of what I can think of):

### Data types

- Number data types: DB2 has many more standard types, such as `SMALLINT`, `INTEGER`, `DOUBLE`, etc. Those don't exist in Oracle SQL (although some exist in PL/SQL). This is important for DDL and for casting and some other use cases, such as the correctness of predicates
- Date data types: Oracle's only difference between `DATE` and `TIMESTAMP` is the fact that `TIMESTAMP` has microseconds. But `DATE` may also contain time information. In DB2, `DATE` has no time information, I think.
- Character data types: Read about the difference between `VARCHAR` and `VARCHAR2` in Oracle
- `NULL`. In Oracle, `NULL` is much more general than in DB2. Before DB2 v9.7, you had to cast `NULL` to any explicit type, e.g. `cast(null as integer)`. That's not necessary in Oracle.

### System objects

- `SYSIBM.DUAL` simply becomes `DUAL`
- Functions: They're all a bit different. You'll have to check case by case. For example, `LOCATE` becomes `INSTR`

### Syntax

- `TRUNCATE IMMEDIATE` becomes `TRUNCATE`
- `EXCEPT` becomes `MINUS`
- DB2's `FETCH FIRST n ROWS ONLY`: There is no such clause in Oracle. You'll have to use `ROWNUM` or `ROW_NUMBER() OVER()` filtering (see this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6033080/speed-of-paged-queries-in-oracle))
- DB2's `MERGE` statement is more powerful than that of Oracle, in case you use this.
- DB2 supports `INSERT INTO .. (..) VALUES (..), (..), (..)`. With Oracle, you'd have to write `INSERT INTO .. SELECT .. UNION ALL SELECT .. UNION ALL SELECT ..`

### Advanced

- If you use stored procedures, they work a bit differently, especially with advanced data types involved, but that's out of scope here.

Your most efficient shot at this might be to use SQL abstraction of some sort. If you're using Java, I would recommend you wrap your SQL statements with [jOOQ](http://www.jooq.org) (Disclaimer: I work for the company behind jOOQ). jOOQ provides API-level abstraction for all of the above facts. A great deal of SQL can be executed both on DB2 and Oracle, without adaptation. We're also working on a more independent translator product: https://www.jooq.org/translate

On a higher level of abstraction, [Hibernate](http://www.hibernate.org/) (or other JPA implementations) can do the same for you

Answer (score 0):

I found out that there are also some differences in the management of character strings.

- DB2 doesn't care about the trailing whitespaces when comparing:

  ```
  /* DB2 */
  SELECT CASE WHEN ('A   ' = 'A') THEN 'true' ELSE 'false' END FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1
  --> true

  /* Oracle */
  SELECT CASE WHEN ('A   ' = 'A') THEN 'true' ELSE 'false' END FROM DUAL
  --> false
  ```
- Oracle considers that `''` equals `NULL`:

  ```
  /* DB2 */
  SELECT CASE WHEN ('' IS NULL) THEN 'true' ELSE 'false' END FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1
  --> false

  /* Oracle */
  SELECT CASE WHEN ('' IS NULL) THEN 'true' ELSE 'false' END FROM DUAL
  --> true
  ```