# Vague count in sql select statements

Tags: sql, oracle

I guess this has been asked in the site before but I can't find it.

I've seen in some sites that there is a vague count over the results of a search. For example, here in stackoverflow, when you search a question, it says +5000 results (sometimes), in gmail, when you search by keywords, it says "hundreds" and in google it says aprox X results. Is this just a way to show the user an easy-to-understand-a-huge-number? or this is actually a  fast way to count results that can be used in a database [I'm learning Oracle at the moment 10g version]? something like "hey, if you get more than 1k results, just stop and tell me there are more than 1k".

Thanks

PS. I'm new to databases.

Comment: good question. i'm looking forward to answers too

Answer (score 3):

Usually this is just a nice way to display a number.

I don't believe there is a way to do what you are asking for in SQL - count does not have an option for counting up until some number.

I also would not assume this is coming from SQL in either gmail, or stackoverflow.
Most search engines will return a total number of matches to a search, and then let you page through results.

As for making an exact number more human readable, here is an example from Rails:

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/NumberHelper.html#method-i-number_to_human

Comment: Stack Overflow is running on SQL Server (as far as I know) and [makes a lot of use of SQL](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/queries). So I'm not sure why you'd claim that this shouldn't be done with SQL?

Comment: I said don't assume it is using SQL, not that you shouldn't use SQL. And actually, SO uses lucene.net: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/stack-overflow-search-now-81-less-crappy/

Answer (score 2):

With Oracle, you can always resort to analytical functions in order to calculate the *exact* number of rows about to be returned. This is an example of such a query:

```
SELECT inner.*, MAX(ROWNUM) OVER(PARTITION BY 1) as TOTAL_ROWS
FROM (
  [... your own, sorted search query ...]
) inner
```

This will give you the total number of rows for your specific subquery. When you want to apply paging as well, you can further wrap these SQL parts as such:

```
SELECT outer.* FROM (
  SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT inner.*,ROWNUM as RNUM, MAX(ROWNUM) OVER(PARTITION BY 1) as TOTAL_ROWS
    FROM (
      [... your own, sorted search query ...]
    ) inner
  ) 
  WHERE ROWNUM < :max_row
) outer
WHERE outer.RNUM > :min_row
```

Replace `min_row` and `max_row` by meaningful values. But beware that calculating the *exact* number of rows can be expensive when you're not filtering using `UNIQUE SCAN` or relatively narrow `RANGE SCAN` operations on indexes. Read more about this here: [Speed of paged queries in Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6033080/speed-of-paged-queries-in-oracle)

As others have said, you can always have an absolute upper limit, such as `5000` to your query using a `ROWNUM <= 5000` filter and then just indicate that there are more than `5000+` results. Note that Oracle can be very good at optimising queries when you apply `ROWNUM` filtering. Find some info on that subject here:

http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_sql_tuning_rownum_equals_one.htm

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how fast this will run, but you can try:

```
SELECT NULL FROM your_tables WHERE your_condition AND ROWNUM <= 1001
```

If count of rows in result will equals to 1001 then total count of records will > 1000.

Answer (score 1):

Vague count is a buffer which will be displayed promptly. If user wants to see more results then he can request more.

It's a performance facility, after displaying the results the sites like google keep searching for more results.

Answer (score 1):

[this question](http://ask.sqlservercentral.com/questions/1782/counting-the-number-of-rows-in-a-table.html) gives some pretty good information

Answer (score 0):

When you do an SQL query you can set a

```
 LIMIT 0, 100
```

for example and you will only get the first hundred answers. so you can then print to your viewer that there are 100+ answers to their request.

For google I couldn't say if they really know there is more than 27'000'000'000 answer to a request but I believe they really do know. There are some standard request that have results stored and where the update is done in the background.